# How long does an old question stay online after downvoting?

Tags: support, downvotes, automatic-deletion

I have only [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34313255/cannot-find-glib-gettext-in-msys2) on Stack Overflow and I answered it after researching myself.

After gaining some reputation here, I got sporadically downvotes on that question and even on the answer at least once. A common problem.

With still four upvotes on the answer and now -1 on the question, will this question be deleted, if more people use it as point maker or dislike the question?

So I got curious: How long would it take to get my question deleted?

Comment: It's not even closed, and so is currently at no risk of being deleted.

Comment: that i know, but i wanted to know when the downvoting continues and it will, is it enough to delete it automatcally.  I don't think it is in any danger to get closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Consult the FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/175248) for insights into how post deletion works.

Specifically speaking, your question wouldn't qualify for any form of automated deletion.

> ### What are the criteria for deletion?
>
> For questions, a post that no longer adds anything to the site should be deleted. Basically, this
> includes most closed questions that cannot be improved and reopened.
> However, it may be beneficial to keep duplicates to aid future users
> in finding the canonical question, as different people may use
> different wordings that cause the canonical question to not show up in
> search.

In your case, your question has an upvoted answer, so won't be auto deleted and you cannot self delete it.

Comment: This is pretty much a link only answer

Comment: In a perfect world, I could close this as a duplicate of the uber-Meta question. But until such a time, this answer is better than a comment which'll get buried and be completely unsearchable for anyone curious about this.

Comment: I totally agree! Just put some of the details of the answer into your answer, is all I'm saying. ;)

Comment: Let me know if you're not ok with this edit